# Turn off Realtime Changes on Firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Im currently developing a chatting app, using firebase, and firebase realtime database as my Database.
I have a users list, and it updates every time a data in list changes. Which i think very bad, performancewise.
Now, how can i turn it off? Im using Kotlin and FirebaseUI RecyclerView.

Comment: so when do you want the user's list to be updated if you don't want a realtime update option?

Comment: when user refreshes the layout

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be updated only once, i.e you do not expect changes to the UI, you can use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method. Check the link to the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once)

If you are looking for a way to implement it in kotlin. check this [tutorial](https://medium.com/a-practical-guide-to-firebase-on-android/storing-and-retrieving-data-from-firebase-with-kotlin-on-android-91c36680771) out.